# Twitter API - Validating Twitter is actually Twitter

Tags: api, twitter, signature

I've been looking around at various APIs, and since twitter seems to be a common discussion point, I'll use it as an example.

A lot of APIs are implementing oAuth which is great for allowing the service to authenicate and authorize the application connecting to it, however, from what I have seen there doesnt seem to be a way for the application to verify that Twitter is actually Twitter (and not a man in the middle based attack)? I would expect to see some kind of signature (using a shared / public key) of the response body which I can use to validate that twitter signed it.

Is it just because currently there isnt really a point to a man in the middle attack with twitter tweets since currently, whats the worst that can happen (and why would someone want to give me invalid tweets)

On this point, if you were to sign the response, what method would you use? Im currently considering a HMAC-SHA1 signature of the response body using a shared key.

Comment: Should have specified - I know you can use SSL for transport security, but seems like a lot of overhead when the data is not sensitive...

Comment: If the data isn't sensitive why do you care where it comes from? It you care, how can you know that once you've verified that the data isn't being sent from somewhere else, or somehow modified?

Comment: Just because it isnt sensitive doesn't mean I dont want to validate the source, some data just isn't 'secretive', couldnt care who intercepts it, but want to validate that it came fom a proper source. For (a bad) example, weather data, dont care who reads it on the way, but if i use that info to determine if I should automatically turn heating on, I want to know it came from the proper source.

As to how to validate it, as per the question, via a signature of some kind, since if you change the data the signature is no longer valid.

Comment: Validating the source only works once; you receive data often, and as I've said below, you can't know the data comes from the source unless you stay in a validated channel.

Comment: @silky, can you explain to me why validating only works once? If you sign every response, and it can only be done with the private key, then you know that it came from that source. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Michael: What I'm saying is that if the process is to 1: sign with twitter.com, then process messages (on a polling basis) against twitter.com, he'll open more (new) connections that haven't been checked. Something could've changed, or messages could simply be modified (by servers in between), so it's useless to do the signing, if it's not done every time, in the same channel (and the message integrity is protected).

Comment: (that is to say, then you know that the response came from a source that has the private key - it doesn't protect against a case where the private key has been stolen, but I don't think @RM is asking for coverage in this situation)

Comment: @silky, I thought @RM was suggesting to sign *every* response.

Comment: Michael: Then you've just invented similar overhead to SSL, and why invent your own possibly flawed scheme when SSL is there, is implemented, and is well known. The answer is that @RM just wants to re-invent the wheel, which is always a bad idea in security.

Comment: @silky, you haven't reinvented SSL at all. There's no encryption whatsoever. And there's no certificate authorities, or anything near that complicated. It's just a signed request. All sorts of web services have signed requests, they're hardly new.

Comment: @silky as below, transport level security (SSL) and message level security are VERY different things. Not sure how signing messages is re-inventing the wheel since many technologies including WS-* enables signing of messages without transport layer security, its just something that REST / POX services in general dont seems to support at the moment, twitter was just an example.

Comment: RM: Signing is not re-inventing the wheel; your question was asking about authenticating the server! (not messages).

Comment: @silky, I didn't read it that way at all. @RM already mentioned using oAuth for the authentication/authorisation side of things. The question is one of verification - ie, ensuring that the responses are coming from where they say they are. I find your characterisation that there is some sort of "personal disagreement" quite inaccurate too - the only "personal" comment I can see is yours stating "you just don't understand what it is you're trying to do". From where I'm standing, you've misunderstood the question, that's all.

Comment: Michael: I read "...Twitter is actually Twitter...", this is specifically the purpose of SSL and trust, hence my post.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the 'trust' part of SSL does.

-- Edit

I note this has been downvoted, but it's important that other readers realise it's due to a personal disagreement, not due to incorrectness.

Comment: SSL seems like a lot of overhead - especially for a service that is receiving hundreds of thousands of requests...

Comment: As I've hinted at in the comment in your post; if you don't validate it and use SSL, even if you check, by some scheme, that it's who you think it is as first, if the connection isn't protected from change (i.e. SSL) it doesn't matter; you can't trust what you're receiving. The bottom line for you is obvious: Either you accept the latency with SSL, or you accept that you don't know where the data is coming from.

Comment: @silky, I think we're looking at two different things here, I want to validate the message, you seem to want to validate the transport mechanism, i.e. if you sign each message you could print it, email it, use UDP do what ever you want with it and integrity can always be maintained. I'm refering to a signing scheme per message, not a once off transport level scheme. (i.e. im refering to HMAC-SH1 hashing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-SHA1 or similar)

Comment: RM: No, we're not, I'm sorry but you just don't understand what it is you're trying to do. I'll leave it to someone else to explain, as for whatever reason, there appears to be a general problem communicating.

Comment: @RM, I agree with you - you're talking about two different things. SSL is for encryption, which you've clearly indicated you don't need. I say HMAC-SHA1 is a good choice for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: SHA1 is not a good choice for any cryptographically-related hashing scheme. (http://valerieaurora.org/hash.html)

Comment: @silky, that's such an awesome comment. Out of interest, which SSL provider do you use?

Comment: Michael: Just because they haven't caught up doesn't mean you shouldn't. I'm guessing there is some attitude in your comment, but there is no real point engaging that here (any moment now it's probably worthwhile flagging this whole discussing as useless; though it is important people realise that SHA1 is actually, effectively, dead).

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET world we use WCF, which has many different security models, including signing (and if desired encrypting) each message/response. This adds up to a non-trivial amount of overhead, but can give you more 'trust' in the security model. You can switch to using binary-serialized data to cut down on the bloat and message size if you desire.

I'm not sure what other Web Service APIs offer in that area, though I'm sure someone else can add further details as needed.

Comment: Yeah thats the sort of thing i mean (signing, not encryption), but for standard REST or POX services such as Twitter.